# How to verify integrity of a .git folder?

Tags: git

I store my git repos in GlusterFS. Due to a split-brain condition, one of the git repos are in split-brain.

Now, is there a command that I can run on the storage boxes to see if any of the data bricks are valid git repos?

Meaning all the object files and other data for a git repos are intact?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To verify the object you can use this simply command:

```
git fsck --full
```

> **`git-fsck`**
> Verifies the connectivity and validity of the objects in the database

**fsck** - **F**ile **S**ystem **C**hec**K**.
The name is taken from the Unix `fsck` command

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck

---

If you want you can also verify the pack separately with but you basically dont need to do it.

> **`git verify-pack`** [-v|--verbose] [-s|--stat-only] [--] .idx
>
> Reads given idx file for packed Git archive created with the git pack-objects command and verifies idx file and the corresponding pack file.

Comment: Apparently *--full* is now the default for git-fsck. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck.